# Insert statement does absolutely nothing when i submit the form

Tags: php, forms, validation

My insert statement does nothing when i try and submit the form its supposed to show the conformation message but nothing shows up at all and it doesnt submit into the database.

And for reference there is no error code that shows up when i click submit its just that nothing happens.

```
  <?php require_once('dbuser.php');?>
<?php
// if the submit button has been selected
if(isset($_POST['submit_registration'])) {
    // assign variable to each for control to capture the values
    $first = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $postal = $_POST['postal_code'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $distance = $_POST['dist'];
    //assign null values for use with the isset function to identify null fields that are missing a value
    $nofirst = null;
    $nolast = null;
    $noemail = null;
    $noaddress1 = null;
    $noaddress2 = '';
    $nocity = null;
    $nostate= null;
    $nopostal = null;
    $nophone = null;
    $nodistance = null;
    // if value of variable is nothing assign something other than null
    if($first=="") {
        $nofirst = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($last==""){
        $nolast = '';
        $novalue ='';
    }
    if($email=="") {
        $noemail = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($address1=="") {
        $noaddress1 = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($address2=="") {
        $noaddress2 = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($city=="") {
        $nocity = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($state=="") {
        $nostate = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($postal=="") {
        $nopostal = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($phone=="") {
        $nophone = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($distance=="") {
        $nodistance = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if(isset($novalue)) {$confim = 'Please enter all values';}
        else {
        $insertsql = "INSERT INTO `runner`(`fname`, `lname`,`email`,`address1`,`address2`,`city`,`state`,`postalcode`, `phone`, `distance`) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$address1','$address2','$city','$state','$postal','$phone','$distance')";
        mysql_query($connect, $insertsql) or die ("Insert failed: ".mysql_error($connect));
        $confirm = 'Thank you for registering!';
        }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Matthew Cromika Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <header><img src="images/eastersealsclevelogo.png" alt="Easter Seals Logo" width="445" height="300"</img> </header>
      <nav>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="signup.php" class="current">Run Sign-Up</a></li>
           <li><a href="refer.php" class="current">Refer-a-Friend</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
    <h1>Sign up for a event!</h1>
     <p>If you would like to join in any of the runs, then feel free to sign up using the form provided below.</p><br>
       <?php {echo $confirm;} ?>
       <form method="post" action="signup.php">
       <form name="signup" title="signup" id="signup">
       <table>
       <tr>
       <td><label for="first_name">First Name:</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" title="first name" ></td>
       <?php if(isset($nofirst)){echo"<span class='errormsg'> First name is required<br></span>";}?>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
       <td><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" title="last name" ></td>
       <?php if(isset($nolast)){echo"<span class='errormsg'> Last Name is required<br></span>";}?>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
       <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
       <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" title="email" ></td>
       <?php if(isset($noemail)){echo"<span class='errormsg'> Your Email is required<br></span>";}?>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
       <td><label for="address1">Address 1:</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" title="address1" ></td>
       <?php if(isset($noaddress1)) {echo"<span class='errormsg'> Your Address is required<br></span>";}?>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
       <td><label for="address2">Address 2:</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" title="address2"></td>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
       <td><label for="city">City:</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" title="city" value="Cleveland" ></td>
       <?php if(isset($nocity)){echo"<span class='errormsg'> Your City is required<br> </span>";}?>
       </tr>
       
       <tr>
       <td><label for="state">State:</label></td>
       <td>
    <select required name="state">
    <option value="state" name="state" title="state">Select A Option</option>>
    <option value="AL" name="AL" title="alabama">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK" name="AK" title="alaska">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ" name="AZ" title="arizona">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR" name="AR" title="arkansas">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA" name="CA" title="california">California</option>
    <option value="CO" name="CO" title="colorado">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT" name="CT" title="connecticut">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE" name="DE" title="delware">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC" name="DC" title="district of columbia">District Of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL" name="FL" title="florida">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA" name="GA" title="georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI" name="HI" title="hawaii">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID" name="ID" title="idaho">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL" name="IL" title="illinois">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN" name="IN" title="indiana">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA" name="IA" title="iowa">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS" name="KA" title="kansas">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY" name="KY" title="kentucky">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA" name="LA" title="louisiana">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME" name="ME" title="maine">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD" name="MD" title="maryland">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA" name="MA" title="massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI" name="MI" title="michigan">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN" name="MN" title="minnesota">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS" name="MS" title="mississippi">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO" name="MO" title="missouri">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT" name="MT" title="montana">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE" name="NE" title="nebraska">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV" name="NV" title="nevada">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH" name="NH" title="new hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ" name="NJ" title="new jersey">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM" name="NM" title="new mexico">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY" name="NY" title="new york">New York</option>
    <option value="NC" name="NC" title="north carolina">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND" name="ND" title="north dakota">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH" name="OH" title="ohio" selected>Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK" name="OK" title="oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR" name="OR" title="oregon">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA" name="PA" title="pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI" name="RI" title="rhode island">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC" name="SC" title="south carolina">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD" name="SD" title="south dakota">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN" name="TN" title="tennessee">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX" name="TX" title="texas">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT" name="UT" title="utah">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT" name="VT" title="vermont">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA" name="VA" title="virginia">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA" name="WA" title="washington">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV" name="WV" title="west virginia">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI" name="WI" title="wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY" name="WY" title="wyoming">Wyoming</option>
</select></td>
    <?php if(isset($nostate)) {echo "<span class='errormsg'>Your state is required<br></span>";}?>
</tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label for="postal_code">Zip Code:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="postal_code" id="postal_code"  title="postal_code" pattern="[\d]{5}(-[\d]{4})" ></td>
    <?php if(isset($nopostal)) {echo "<span class='errormsg'> Your postal code is required<br></span>";}?>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td><label for="phone">Phone:</label></td>
    <td><input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" title="phone" ></td>
    <?php if(isset($nophone)) {echo "<span class='errormsg'> Your Phone number is required<br></span>";}?>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td><label for="distance">Distance:</label></td><br>
    <td><input type="radio" name="dist" value="1mile" id="dist" title="1mile" checked ><label>1 Mile</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="dist" value="5k" id="dist" title="5k"><label>5K</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="dist" value="10k" id="dist" title="10k"><label>10K</label></td>
    <?php if(isset($nodist)) {echo "<span class='errormsg'> You must choose a distance</span>";}?>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>  <input type="submit" name="submit_registration" id="submit_registration" title="submit" value="Submit Form"></td>
    <td>  <input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" title="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="location.href='index.html'"></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
       <p>If you would like to invite a friend then click <a href="refer.php">here</a> and have them join in!
    </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Your `mysql_query($connect, $insertsql) ...` has the params in the wrong order. It should be `mysql_query($insertsql, $connect) ....`.

Comment: Also, why do you have nested forms - `<form method="post" action="signup.php"> <form name="signup" title="signup" id="signup">`?

Comment: Forms within forms is bound to throw up some problems, also take a look at prepared statements with mysqli_ or PDO - It's way more secure; your code is open to all kinds of attacks.

Comment: I Fixed the forms and changed the params to the right order but still get nothing when i submit it.